# Load document from database with office javascript api

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I'm saving the document to a DB extracting the base64 file with `Office.context.document.getFileAsync`, but I need the counterpart to load my document, I tried with `thisDocument.body.insertFileFromBase64`, but I't doesn't load layout setting, header, footer etc., I also tried a method from the beta `context.application.createDocument(base64file)` but this opens a new instance of word and this does not fit my app requirement.  Are there any other alternatives? Can this be done with and add-in?